Is there an L2 Lagrange point for Mercury that lies in the shadow?
Or is it just too far away to be shadowed from the photosphere of the sun?
Just wondering if some futuristic science/observation station could ever be placed there.
I know about the polar craters that are always dark.  Otherwise it looks like Mercury is beyond a human visit.

I'm afraid not. The umbral limit for Mercury will vary (as a result of Mercury's eccentric orbit) but is about 170,000 km from the planet.  The Lagrange point (again it moves due to the non-circular orbit) is about $R(\mu/3)^{1/3}$, where R is the Mercury-sun distance and $\mu$ is the mass ratio.  That gives a Lagrange point that is about 2500,000 km from Mercury. An order of magnitude greater.
Human exploration of Mercury is probably unlike in the foreseeable future.  It's also probably not a very interesting place for humans to visit in person.  Mercury is one for the robots.

+1, further reading: ...the Sun-Mercury libration points (all five of them) are merely mathematical curiosities of a hypothetical two-body system. ...the actual gravitational effects of Venus and Earth (both much larger than Mercury, but also farther away) make the two-body approximation "less than useful" for any real world systems.
